# Filter a QuerySet based on matching field in another QuerySet but restricted to an associated field in the other QuerySet

Tags: python, django, filter, django-orm

I am trying to create a filter based off two query sets of two related models (both already previously filtered). The first returns a list of IDs and concepts (names) with associated values (definitions).

**dqs**: ID + concept + definitions + associated language (any one of four)

For example:

```
<QuerySet [<Definition: Definition (en) for #39: CBD, central business district: definition text>, <Definition: Definition (en) for #184: migration: definition text...>
```

The second also has IDs and concepts which may or may not have matching values in the first list.

**tqs**: ID1 + concept1 + terms (lang 1); ID1 + concept1 + terms (lang 2)...ID2 + concept1 + terms (lang 1) etc.

For example:

```
<QuerySet [<Translation: “other language term entry” (fr) for #1: abiotic component>, <Translation: “abiotic component” (en) for #1: abiotic component>, <Translation: “yet another language term entry” (es) for #1: abiotic component>...>
```

IDs and concepts (expressed in English, the source language) are not language specific. Terms and definitions are language specific. So each concept+ID is associated with term entries and definitions in four different languages.

I need to filter tqs so that it only displays entries that have matching IDs in dqs, and only in the language in which the definition search query was matched (otherwise it will show all four entries associated with the matching ID).

A bit more information below.

The following part of the def describes what happens when a search is made in the glossary matching a string in the definition (which is related to a specific entry).

```
if data['definitions_show_partial_matches']:
    if case_filter:
        dqs = dqs.filter(text__contains=search_string)
    else:
        dqs = dqs.filter(text__icontains=search_string)
```

data['definitions_show_partial_matches'] is a BooleanField form - the user indicates in a checkbox whether or not the search also includes the definition text. case_filter indicates whether the search should be case sensitive.

It is possible for more than one language to appear in dqs after filtering, if the string appears in multiple definitions associated with multiple languages.

I have a makeshift solution for matching the IDs:

```
ids = []
for d in dqs:
    ids.append(d.concept.id)
tqs = tqs.filter(concept__in=ids)
```

However, this is probably not very efficient. I don't know how to apply concept__in directly in another query set without first extracting the IDs to a list. I've thought of enumerating the for loop, but this is apparently also not a very good idea.

All this is followed by code that efficiently creates a results list with truncated definitions and a maximum number of results.

dqs only displays the matching definitions. Therefore, I need to apply a filter to tqs so that entries associated with matching IDs are not displayed in all four languages.

I also need to build in a check so that if the match took place in English, I need to use the "source_language" field in the related Glossary model, instead of "other_languages", and vice versa. To show how these as well as the concept field are related to Glossary and how I solved a related issue, here is some code from a template ("current_language" is a passed variable from the view):

```
{% with used_languages=concept.glossary.other_languages.all|dictsort:"iso_code" %}
  {% if used_languages %}
    <div class="language_link_list">
        {% if current_language.name != "English" %}
            <a href="{% url "concept_detail_for_language" pk=concept.pk lang=concept.glossary.source_language.pk %}" class="language_link">{{ concept.glossary.source_language.name }}</a>
        {% endif %}
...
        {% for lang in used_languages %}
            {% if lang.pk != current_language.pk %}
                <a href="{% url "concept_detail_for_language" pk=concept.pk lang=lang.pk %}" class="language_link">{{ lang.name }}</a>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <br>
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

But this allows the checking of values against an already known value and applying it element by element, instead of a single filter command, where my problem is that the value can change depending on the position of an entry in another query set, and/or the value of a related field in that query set.

I feel like it should not be complicated - I've thought of the following:

- using "update" - but there is not just one value to compare against
- using "annotate" - but a definition already has an associated language, so it should not be necessary?
- using Q() or prefetch_related expressions somehow?

I've been reading through a lot of examples but somehow none of them are quite related to what I'm trying to do.

Thanks!

EDIT: Here are the relevant bits from the relevant models. It's an adaptation from an online project under the GNU GPL. I've removed some comments as well as the name but it shouldn't be a problem if its public.

```
class Translation(models.Model, ConceptLangUrlMixin):
    concept = models.ForeignKey(Concept, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_("concept"))
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name=_("language"))
    translation_text = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=_("translation text"))
    administrative_status = models.ForeignKey(AdministrativeStatus, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name=_("administrative status"))
    administrative_status_reason = models.ForeignKey(AdministrativeStatusReason, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name=_("administrative status reason"))
    note = models.TextField(blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("translation")
        verbose_name_plural = _("translations")
        ordering = ['concept', 'language']

    def __str__(self):
        trans_data = {
            'term': self.translation_text,
            'iso_code': self.language_id,
            'concept': self.concept
        }
        return _("“%(term)s” (%(iso_code)s) for %(concept)s") % trans_data

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        update_repr_cache = kwargs.pop("update_repr_cache", True)
        super(Translation, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if update_repr_cache:
            self.concept.update_repr_cache()

    def cmp_key(self):
        # used to sort terms according to their perceived worth
        keys = {
                "preferredTerm-admn-sts": 0,
                "": 1,
                None: 1,
                "admittedTerm-admn-sts": 2,
                "supersededTerm-admn-sts": 3,
                "deprecatedTerm-admn-sts": 4,
        }
        # We return a tuple with the "quality" key, and the text to allow
        # alphabetic sorting for all adminitted terms, for example.
        return (keys.get(self.administrative_status_id, 1), self.translation_text.lower())

class Definition(models.Model, ConceptLangUrlMixin):
    concept = models.ForeignKey(Concept, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_("concept"))
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name=_("language"))
    text = models.TextField(verbose_name=_("definition text"))
    source = models.URLField(blank=True, verbose_name=_("source"))
    history = HistoricalRecords()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("definition")
        verbose_name_plural = _("definitions")
        unique_together = ("concept", "language")

    def __str__(self):
        text = self.text
        concept = force_text(self.concept)
        if len(concept) > 40 and len(text) > 150:
            boundary = concept.find(",", 0, 35)
            if boundary < 0:
                concept = concept[:35] + "…"
            else:
                concept = concept[:boundary]

        trans_data = {
            'iso_code': self.language_id,
            'concept': concept,
            'text': text
        }
        return _("Definition (%(iso_code)s) for %(concept)s: %(text)s") % trans_data

class Concept(models.Model):
    glossary = models.ForeignKey(Glossary, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_("glossary"))
    subject_field = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='concepts_in_subject_field', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name=_("subject field"))
    broader_concept = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='narrower_concepts', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name=_("broader concept"))
    related_concepts = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, verbose_name=_("related concepts"))
    # This keeps a readable version cached in this table so that no joining
    # with Translation is required for a human readable form.
    repr_cache = models.CharField(max_length=200, editable=False, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("representation"))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("concept")
        verbose_name_plural = _("concepts")
        ordering = ['id']

    def __str__(self):
        if self.repr_cache:
            return self.repr_cache
        return _("Concept #%(concept_id)d") % {'concept_id': self.id}

    def update_repr_cache(self):
        if not self.id:
            return
        src_translations = self.translation_set.filter(
                language_id=self.glossary.source_language_id,
        )
        repr_ = self.repr_from(src_translations)
        if repr_:
            self.repr_cache = repr_
            self.save(update_fields=['repr_cache'])

    def repr_from(self, translations):
        translations = sorted(translations, key=lambda t: t.cmp_key())
        repr_ = ', '.join(t.translation_text for t in translations[:4])[:200]
        repr_ = "#%d: %s" % (self.id, repr_)
        return repr_

    def prev_concept(self):
        """The previous concept in the same glossary."""
        return Concept.objects.filter(
                glossary=self.glossary,
                id__lt=self.id,
        ).only("id", "repr_cache").order_by('-id').first()

    def next_concept(self):
        """The next concept in the same glossary."""
        return Concept.objects.filter(
                glossary=self.glossary,
                id__gt=self.id,
        ).only("id", "repr_cache").order_by('id').first()

    def other_concepts(self):
        """Some surrounding concepts in the glossary."""
        previous_concepts = Concept.objects.filter(
                glossary=self.glossary,
                id__lt=self.pk,
        ).only("id", "repr_cache").order_by('-id')[:5]
        next_concepts = Concept.objects.filter(
                glossary=self.glossary,
                id__gte=self.pk,
        ).only("id", "repr_cache").order_by('id')[:6]

        return itertools.chain(reversed(previous_concepts), next_concepts)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('concept_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


class Glossary(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, verbose_name=_("name"))
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name=_("description"))
    source_language = models.ForeignKey(Language, related_name='+', on_delete=models.PROTECT, default='en', verbose_name=_("source language"))
    other_languages = models.ManyToManyField(Language, blank=True, related_name='+', verbose_name=_("other languages"))
    subject_fields = models.ManyToManyField('Concept', related_name='glossary_subject_fields', blank=True, verbose_name=_("subject fields"))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("glossary")
        verbose_name_plural = _("glossaries")
        permissions = (
            ('owner', 'Owner of this glossary'),
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('glossary_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

EDIT: Based on a suggestion on Reddit I've tried this:

```
tqs = tqs.filter(language__in=dqs.values_list('language', flat=True)).filter(concept__id__in=dqs.values_list('concept__id', flat=True))
```

It looks much better but doesn't quite work. It seems to ignore the case filter applied to dqs just before. When I search for "GIS" and case sensitivity is turned off, search results include definitions that do not contains either the strings "gis" or "GIS". Here is the relevant code but with the newest filter to indicate correct indentation:

```
   if data['definitions_show_partial_matches']:
        if case_filter:
            dqs = dqs.filter(text__contains=search_string)
        else:
            dqs = dqs.filter(text__icontains=search_string)
        tqs = tqs.filter(language__in=dqs.values_list('language', flat=True)).filter(concept__id__in=dqs.values_list('concept__id', flat=True))
```

Comment: Can you add the models to the qestion?

Comment: I've added the code.

Comment: I've added an alternative filter that doesn't quite work but seems to be closer to a solution.